# HashMap / ArrayList wont take multiple values per key

Tags: java, object, hashmap, key

I want to create a HashMap that has a key of type String and a value of a List of Objects that is set up in another class.

The code I have tried works in that it adds a key and a value to the map, but wont add multiple values to 1 key. I.E I would like Key x to have values 1,2 and 3 but it just seems to overwrite the last value rather than add another one.

This is my current code:

```
    public class LeagueAdmin {

    private Map<String, List<Team>> teams;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class LeagueAdmin
     *
     */
    public LeagueAdmin() {
        this.teams = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public void addTeam(String division, Team team) {
        if(!this.teams.containsKey(division))
        {
            List<Team> Team = new ArrayList<>();
            Team.add(team);
            this.teams.put(division, Team);
        } else {
            List<Team> newTeam = this.teams.get(division);
        }
    }
        }
```

As I said, when I add multiple values to the key string 'top' for example  I expect 'top' to show me all the values added to it, instead it only shows the latest one added. Also as mentioned the Team object is handled in a separate class file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your else is incomplete. You make a list but never add to it when it sees that the key `division` exists. Add

```
newTeam.add(team);
```

to your else statement

Comment: Thanks for the quick response,
That for some reason throws up more errors, i.e:
"cannot find symbol - method add(Team)" eventhough it's used in the above if statement

Comment: sorry. Should be newTeam.add(team) and this.teams.put(division(newTeam). Also, it is bad practice to use uppercase letters for the first word of a variable (your `ArrayList Team`)

Comment: That works perfectly. And thanks for the tip regarding naming conventions.